# ncurses window scrolling not working even with scrollok set to true

Tags: c, ncurses

I am writing an ncurses file manager in C with a UI like ranger file manager. 
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>


/*
    Creates a new window with dimensions `height` and `width` starting at `starty` and `startx`
*/
WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{   
    WINDOW *local_win;

    local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);

    return local_win;
}


/*
    Returns number of files in `char* directory`
*/
int getNumberofFiles(char* directory)
{
    int len=0;
    DIR *pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirent;

    pDir = opendir (directory);
    if (pDir == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", directory);
        exit(0);
    }

    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        // Skip hidden files
      if(pDirent->d_name[0] != '.' )
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}


/*
    Stores all the file names in `char* directory` to `char *target[]`
*/
void getFiles(char* directory, char* target[])
{
    int i = 0;
    DIR *pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirent;

    pDir = opendir (directory);
    if (pDir == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", directory);
        exit(0);
    }

    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        // Skip hidden files
        if(pDirent->d_name[0] != '.')
          target[i++] = strdup(pDirent->d_name);
    }

    closedir (pDir);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // To store number of files in directory
    int len=0;
    // Counter variable
    int i = 0;
    // Direcotry to be opened
    char* dir;

    // Get UID of user
    uid_t uid = getuid();
    // Get home directory of user from UID
    struct passwd *info = getpwuid(uid);

    // No Path is given in arguments
    // Set Path as $HOME
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        dir = info->pw_dir;
    }

    // Path is given in arguments
    // Set Path as the argument
    else if(argc == 2)
    {
        dir = argv[1];

        // Relative Path Given
        if(dir[0] != '/')
        {
            // Add path of $HOME before the Relative Path
            char temp[250] = "";
            strcat(temp,info->pw_dir);
            strcat(temp,"/");
            strcat(temp,dir);
            dir = temp;
        }   
    }
    // Incorrect Useage
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect Useage\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Get number of files in the home directory
    len = getNumberofFiles(dir);

    // ncurses initialization
    initscr();
    raw();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    // Shows current directory
    WINDOW *current_win;
    // Shows child directory preview
    WINDOW *preview_win;
    int startx, starty, midx, midy, maxx, maxy;

    // Index of currently selected item in `char* directories`
    int selection = 0;
    char ch;
    do 
    {
        len = getNumberofFiles(dir);
        char* directories[len];
        getFiles(dir, directories);

        getmaxyx(stdscr, maxy, maxx);

        // Make the two windows side-by-side
        current_win = create_newwin(maxy, maxx/2+3, 0, 0);
        preview_win = create_newwin(maxy, maxx/2 -1, 0, maxx/2 + 1);

        // Print all the elements and highlight the selection
        for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
        {
            if(i==selection)
                wattron(current_win, A_STANDOUT);
            else
                wattroff(current_win, A_STANDOUT);
            wmove(current_win,i+1,2);
            wprintw(current_win, "%s\n", directories[i]);
        }

        char* selected_file = directories[selection];
        char next_dir[250] = "";
        char prev_dir[250] = "";
        char *p;

        // Get path of parent directory
        strcat(prev_dir, dir);
        p = strrchr(dir,'/');
        prev_dir[p-dir] = '\0';

        // Parent directory is root
        if(prev_dir[0] != '/')
            prev_dir[0] = '/';

        // Get path of child directory
        strcat(next_dir, dir);
        strcat(next_dir, "/");
        strcat(next_dir, directories[selection]);
        int len_preview = getNumberofFiles(next_dir);
        char* next_directories[len_preview];
        getFiles(next_dir, next_directories);

        for( i=0; i<len_preview; i++ )
        {
            wmove(preview_win,i+1,2);
            wprintw(preview_win, "%s\n", next_directories[i]);
        }

        wattroff(current_win, A_STANDOUT);
        box(current_win,0,0);
        box(preview_win,0,0);
        wrefresh(current_win);
        wrefresh(preview_win);

        // Keybindings
        switch( ch = getch() ) {
            case 'k':
                selection--;
                selection = ( selection < 0 ) ? len-1 : selection;
                break;
            case 'j':
                selection++;
                selection = ( selection > len-1 ) ? 0 : selection;
                break;
            case 'l':
                strcpy(dir, next_dir);
                selection = 0;
                break;
            case 'h':
                strcpy(dir, prev_dir);
                selection = 0;
                break;
            case 'g':
                selection = 0;
                break;
            case 'G':
                selection = len-1;
                break;
        }

        // Free Memory
        for( i=0; i<len_preview; i++ )
        {
            free(next_directories[i]);
        }

        for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
        {
            free(directories[i]);
        }
    } while( ch != 'q');

    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

Basically, there are two windows rendered side-by-side. One is `current_win` which shows all the files in the present directory and the other is `preview_win` which shows all the files in the selected directory's child directory.

The problem is, when the present directory has a lot of files, the windows doesn't scrolls when the selection goes outside the window. I tried
`scrollok(current_win, TRUE);` but it automatically scrolls to the bottom-right and stays that way.

How can make it work?

(also for some reason, the shell remains blank after opening the compiled binary until a key is pressed)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the example, this chunk has a problem:

```
    for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
    {
        if(i==selection)
            wattron(current_win, A_STANDOUT);
        else
            wattroff(current_win, A_STANDOUT);
        wmove(current_win,i+1,2);
        wprintw(current_win, "%s\n", directories[i]);
    }
```

If the **`len`** value is greater than the number of rows in the window, the **`wmove`** call will fail—leaving the cursor where the **`wprintw`** call puts it.  Without enabling `scrollok`, that will be the lower-right of the window. But that (with `scrollok` enabled) that would still be the last line of *current_win* (lower left in this case).  If you take out the `wmove` calls and enabled `scrollok`, the result would be more as you expected.

The same problem exists in the loop for *preview_win*.

The question at the very end asks about a blank screen: that's because in this chunk

```
    wrefresh(current_win);
    wrefresh(preview_win);

    // Keybindings
    switch( ch = getch() ) {
```

the **`getch`** call does a

```
wrefresh(stdscr);
```

which overwrites the windows that were just painted.  You could change that `wgetch` to

```
switch ( ch = wgetch(current_win) ) {
```

and *stdscr* wouldn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was able to solve the blank screen in the beginning by adding wgetch(current_win) but I am still having the same problem even after removing wmove() and setting scrollok to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling you get in a window with `scrollok` is very simple. When you write past the end, it inserts a blank line at the bottom. That's it. The line at the top that disappears? It's gone. Not kept in some off-screen buffer. Gone forever. It's not some kind of interactive, bidirectional scrolling. It doesn't know where your "selection" is, and couldn't do anything with that information anyway.

To do reverse scrolling, you can use `wscrl`. Like forward scrolling, it just adds a blank line (at the top). It's your responsibility to repaint the information that belongs in that line.

It might be easier to use a slightly higher level interface, the curses [pad](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html).

Create a pad big enough to hold the full list, and paint the top portion with `prefresh`. When the selection moves out of the visible area, call `prefresh` again with updated coordinates to tell it to show a portion of the pad that includes the new selection.

Comment: pads look interesting. I can't understand how prefresh works though. what do those arguments mean?